# How copy a row from a data frame to another df and turn it in a column in one go?

Tags: r

I have df1 with several rows and columns that I want to copy a only row and turn it into a column in df2 which I want to store the years e gross savings (% of gdp), to make like this:

```
  year    percentGDP
1 1980    17.8 
2 1981    15.4
3 1982    16.5
4 1983    14.2
5 1984    10.3
  ...     ...
```

But when a tried, columns like "percentGDP.X1980" were created and the values of columns were repeated:

```
df2 <- data.frame(year = c("1980":"1990"), percentGDP = c(df1[1,1:11])) 

year    percentGDP.X1980   percentGDP.X1981
1 1980    17.8               15.4
2 1981    17.8               15.4
3 1982    17.8               15.4
4 1983    17.8               15.4
5 1984    17.8               15.4
  ...     ...                ...
```

df1 is similar to this:

```
   Country   X1980 X1981 X1982 X1983 X1984 X1985 X1986 X1987 X1988 X1989 X1990
1  Brazil    17.8  15.4  16.5  14.2  10.3  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "in one go?"

Comment: Also what does `Country` have to do with your final data?

Comment: When I tried it manually (one by one), it worked. But there is no way to do that when you have so many columns.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I wanted show how is the first data frame which the data of gross savings came from. So I just want to get the values of a country's row and turn it in a column to the 'df2' which also have other column with years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the liberty of excluding the first column which is the country and adjusted the indices 1:11 to 2:12.

```
df2 <- data.frame(year = c(1980:1990), percentGDP = as.numeric(df1[1,2:12]))
```

Output

```
> df2
   year percentGDP
1  1980       17.8
2  1981        5.4
3  1982       16.5
4  1983       14.2
5  1984       10.3
6  1985       11.6
7  1986       12.7
8  1987       13.8
9  1988       14.9
10 1989       15.0
11 1990       16.1
```